# Creating a star in C++

Tags: c++, console, escaping, codeblocks, iostream

I'm  attempting to make a star in codeblocks IDE. To create the star I'm trying to incorporate the "`\`" backslash, However when I build and run the program the backslash is omitted.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << " /\\ " << '\n';
    std::cout << "<  >" << '\n';
    std::cout << "//\\" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/ahK7oz34q)

Looked up a solution online which suggested using two backslashes because backslash is an "executable" ( possibly wrong on definition). The solution did work for the first line but the end of the star is missing one leg, any ideas as to why?

I also tried Triple back slashes for the last line but I'm presented with the same problem.

Comment: "The solution did work for the first line but the end of the star is missing one leg, any ideas as to why?" Character sequence `\\ ` produces single `\ ` in output. If you want two `\ ` in output, what do you need to do?

Comment: On topic: Use `R`aw string literals when you mix in backslashes. `std::cout << R"aw(//\\)aw";` will print two forward slashes and two backslahes.

Comment: `cout << "⭐️\n";`

Comment: If two backslashes produced one backslash on the first line, why did you think it would produce two on the last?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks, I thought I only had to worry about the first backslash!

Comment: @molbdnilo haha I tried 3 and got the same result, so i thought I was creating some sort of instruction I didnt want to create.

Comment: @Oersted I'm not convinced, that these kind of edits really improve such questions. Let alone the didactic effects for the OP doing such themselves as requested gets lost.

Comment: @Oersted -- I suggest to not edit the question to do what the OP was supposed to do.  It takes mere seconds to copy and paste text into the edit window, and the OP should have been able to do that.

Answer (score 5):

Besides using another `\` backslash to print a single one escaping, you may use a [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to better see what's the final output:

```
std::cout << R"(
     /\
    <  >
     \/
)";
```